# How to parse Map<string,string> from HDFS with RCFile storage format using mapreduce?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hdfs

In hive, there is one column with type `Map<string,string>`. I want to parse map's key-value info from hdfs using mapreduce. Function map as follows:

```
void map(LongWritable key, BytesRefArrayWritable value, Context context) {
    Text text = new Text();
    // this is the map column
    BytesRefWritable m  = value.get(1);
    text.set(m.getData(), m.getStart(), m.getLength())
    context.write(text, NullWritable.get())
}
```

Then I read from the output file, and find that the key-value parse as follows:
`key1:value1key2:value2...`
which I cant't parse the key-value pair without any separator.
So, how to parse `Map<string,string>` from hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer this question myself.

In hdfs, the key-value pairs in Map or elements in Array are separated by **\002**. And the separator between key and value is **\003**. According this, we can parse all the elements in hdfs.